# Remove a life from my game when dot passes certain point?

Tags: racket

I'm designing a game for a class where:

- A colored dot appears from the right side of the screen and moves across the screen to the left on a fixed horizontal axis.
- When the dot reaches the middle, the player needs to press a key corresponding to its color. If done at the right time, the score increases by one.
- If not, the player loses one life.

I'm having trouble with the following:

- [SOLVED] Adding a new dot to the list of dots at random intervals in the game. This will make it so the dots don't appear linearly, and two dots can be generated right after one another.
- [SOLVED] Moving the dots across the screen left to right.
- [SOLVED] Removing the correct dot when it's in the hitbox area.
- Removing a life if a dot goes offscreen.

The language used here is **intermediate student with lambda.**

Currently, when I press 1 for red, it will remove it as long as a red dot is the first in the list. I need a function that removes that *specific* red dot.

Here's the code so far; know that it's not finished and thus not working as I intend it to.

```
; Color Match


; Game structures
(define-struct dot [x color])
(define-struct cm [dots score lives state])

; Constants
(define width 800)
(define height (/ width (/ 16 9)))
(define h-w (/ width 2))
(define h-h (/ height 2))
(define arrow (beside (rectangle 25 10 "solid" "black")
                                             (rotate 135 (right-triangle 18 18 "solid" "black"))))

(define background (empty-scene width height))
(define bars (place-images
    (list
     (circle (/ width 25) "outline" "black")
     (rectangle (+ width 2) (- height 375) "outline" "black"))
    (list
     (make-posn h-w h-h)
     (make-posn h-w h-h))
  background))

; Game
(define (main ws)
  (big-bang (make-cm empty 0 3 "start")
            [on-tick tock]
            [to-draw render]
            [on-release interact]
            ))

;; random-color: number -> string
;; consumes a number and returns a color
;; string for the given number
(define (random-color n)
  (cond
    [(= n 0) "red"]
    [(= n 1) "blue"]
    [(= n 2) "green"]
    [(= n 3) "yellow"]
    [else (error "Invalid color chosen.")]))

;; draw-dot: structure -> image
;; consumes a dot structure and draws it as an image

(define (draw-dot struct)
  (cond
    [(string=? (dot-color struct) "red") (overlay
                                    (rotate 90 arrow)
                                    (circle (/ width 25) "outline" "black")
                                    (circle (/ width 25) "solid" (dot-color struct)))]
    [(string=? (dot-color struct) "blue") (overlay
                                    (rotate 270 arrow)
                                    (circle (/ width 25) "outline" "black")
                                    (circle (/ width 25) "solid" (dot-color struct)))]
    [(string=? (dot-color struct) "green") (overlay
                                    (flip-horizontal arrow)
                                    (circle (/ width 25) "outline" "black")
                                    (circle (/ width 25) "solid" (dot-color struct)))]
    [(string=? (dot-color struct) "yellow") (overlay
                                    arrow
                                    (circle (/ width 25) "outline" "black")
                                    (circle (/ width 25) "solid" (dot-color struct)))]))


;; tock: color-match -> color-match
;; placeholder for later worldstate
(define (tock ws)
  (cond
    [(string=? (cm-state ws) "play")
     (make-cm (move-dots (add-dot? (random 50) (cm-dots ws)))
              (+ (cm-score ws) 1)
              (cm-lives ws)
              "play")]
    [else ws]))

;; add-dot?: number, list of dots -> list of dots
;; consumes list of dots and number and adds a new dot
;; to the list of dots
(define (add-dot? n lod)
  (cond
    [(= n 1) (cons (make-dot (+ width 25) (random-color (random 4))) lod)]
    [else lod]))

;; render: color-match -> image
;; consumes the current color-match structure and calls the appropriate
;; helper function.
(define (render ws)
  (cond
    [(string=? (cm-state ws) "start") (render-start ws)]
    [(string=? (cm-state ws) "play") (render-play ws)]
    [(string=? (cm-state ws) "pause") (render-pause ws)]
    [else (error "Invalid gamestate chosen.")]))

;; render-start: color-match -> image
;; helps the render function by displaying the current state
;; as an image.
(define (render-start ws)
  (place-image
   (above
    (text "Instructions" (/ width 20) "red")
    (text "Colored shapes will begin appearing from the right of the screen." (/ width 50) "black")
    (text "Once they reach the bar in the middle, press the appropriate key." (/ width 50) "black")
    (text "1: Red" (/ width 50) "red")
    (text "2: Blue" (/ width 50) "blue")
    (text "3: Green" (/ width 50) "green")
    (text "4: Yellow" (/ width 50) "yellow"))
   h-w
   h-h
   background))


;; draw-dots: list of dots -> image
;; consumes a list of dots and draws them
;; according to their color
(define (draw-dots lod)
  (cond
    [(empty? lod) bars]
    [else (place-image (draw-dot (first lod))
                       (dot-x (first lod))
                       h-h
                       (draw-dots (rest lod)))]))

;; is-visible?: dot -> boolean
;; consumes a dot and determines if it is currently visible
;; on the canvas
(define (is-visible? dot)
  (cond
    [(> (dot-x dot) -25) #true]
    [else #false]))

;; move-dot: dot -> number
;; consumes a dot and returns its new
;; x coordinate
(define (move-dot dot)
  (- (dot-x dot) 10))

;; new-dot: dot -> dot
;; consumes a dot and returns a new dot by calling
;; the move-dot function
(define (new-dot dot)
  (make-dot (move-dot dot) (dot-color dot)))

;; move-dots: list of dots -> list of dots
;; consumes a list of dots and moves them across the
;; canvas as long as they are in view
(define (move-dots lod)
  (cond
    [(empty? lod) empty]
    [(not (is-visible? (first lod))) (rest lod)]
    [else (cons (new-dot (first lod)) (move-dots (rest lod)))]))


;; draw-bars: cm -> image
;; consumes the world state and returns the image of bars
(define (draw-bars ws)
  (place-image (draw-dots (cm-dots ws))
               h-w
               h-h
               bars))


;; render-play: color-match -> image
;; helps the render function by displaying the current state
;; as an image.
(define (render-play ws)
  (overlay/align "left" "top" (current-lives ws)
  (underlay/align "right" "top" (place-image (draw-bars ws)
                                             h-w
                                             h-h 
                                             background)
                  (current-score ws))))

;; current-lives: cm -> image
;; consumes the worldstate and displays the
;; current life count
(define (current-lives ws)
  (text (string-append "Lives: " (number->string (cm-lives ws))) 18 "red"))

;; current-score: cm -> image
;; consumes the worldstate and shows the
;; current score
(define (current-score ws)
  (text (string-append "Score: " (number->string (cm-score ws))) 18 "black"))

;; render-pause: color-match -> image
;; helps the render function by displaying the current state
;; as an image.
(define (render-pause ws)
  (place-image
  (text "paused" (/ width 20) "red")
  h-w
  (- h-h 75)
  (render-play ws)))

; (define (check-dot lod key)
;   (cond
;     [(empty? lod) empty]
;     [(and (< (- h-w (+ (/ width 25) 25)) (dot-x (first lod)) (+ h-w (+ (/ width 25) 25))) (string=? (dot-color (first lod)) "red") (key=? key "1")) (remove (make-dot (dot-x (first lod)) "red") lod)]
;     [(and (< (- h-w (+ (/ width 25) 25)) (dot-x (first lod)) (+ h-w (+ (/ width 25) 25))) (string=? (dot-color (first lod)) "blue") (key=? key "2")) (remove (make-dot (dot-x (first lod)) "blue") lod)]
;     [(and (< (- h-w (+ (/ width 25) 25)) (dot-x (first lod)) (+ h-w (+ (/ width 25) 25))) (string=? (dot-color (first lod)) "green") (key=? key "3")) (remove (make-dot (dot-x (first lod)) "green") lod)]
;     [(and (< (- h-w (+ (/ width 25) 25)) (dot-x (first lod)) (+ h-w (+ (/ width 25) 25))) (string=? (dot-color (first lod)) "yellow") (key=? key "4")) (remove (make-dot (dot-x (first lod)) "yellow") lod)]
;     [else lod]))


;; correct-dot? cm, lod, string -> list of dots
;; consumes the world state, its list of dots, a string, and sorts
;; out dots that have been correctly selected
(define (correct-dot? lod c)
  (cond
    [(empty? lod) empty]
    [(and (< (- h-w (+ (/ width 25) 1)) (dot-x (first lod)) (+ h-w (+ (/ width 25) 1))) (string=? (dot-color (first lod)) c)) (correct-dot? (rest lod) c)]
    [else (cons (first lod) (correct-dot? (rest lod) c))]))

;; is-it?: list of dots, key -> list of dots
;; consumes a list of dots and a key and returns
;; a new list of dots with one removed if the
;; conditions are met for it
(define (is-it? lod key)
  (cond
    [(empty? lod) empty]
    [(key=? key "up") (correct-dot? lod "red")]
    [(key=? key "down") (correct-dot? lod "blue")]
    [(key=? key "left") (correct-dot? lod "green")]
    [(key=? key "right") (correct-dot? lod "yellow")]
    [else lod]))

;; interact: color-match, key -> color-match
;; consumes the current color-match state and returns
;; a new one depending on which key is pressed.
(define (interact ws key)
  (cond
    [(string=? (cm-state ws) "play")
     (cond
       [(key=? key "p") (make-cm (cm-dots ws)
                                 (cm-score ws)
                                 (cm-lives ws)
                                 "pause")]
       [else (make-cm (is-it? (cm-dots ws) key)
                      (cm-score ws)
                      (cm-lives ws)
                      (cm-state ws))])]
    [(and (string=? (cm-state ws) "start") (key=? key "p")) (make-cm (cm-dots ws)
                                                                     (cm-score ws)
                                                                     (cm-lives ws)
                                                                     "play")]
    [(and (string=? (cm-state ws) "pause") (key=? key "p")) (make-cm (cm-dots ws)
                                                                     (cm-score ws)
                                                                     (cm-lives ws)
                                                                     "play")]
    [else ws]))

(main 200)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ISL lists are not mutable so the only thing that you are able to do is create a new list with everything except what you want to remove. You could possibly filter through the list with your procedure only accepting the elements you want to keep

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've done exactly that; and now I'm moving on to altering the score and life count once it's correctly sorted out, or if it's missed.